# firebase import error with node, react and Chakra

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image: This is the error i am receiving]

So I am receiving this error when I run "yarn dev" in the projects directory.

code (firebaseConfig.js):

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  databaseURL: 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
  measurementId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth();

export { auth }
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is wondering, i just deleted my analytics and then it worked, don't even know why i got that error